# Setting a column default value on angular ui grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a table with lots of columns and some rows may have undefined values so I want to show a default text instead of an empty cell depending on the column. How can I set that value?

I would expect something like this:

```
columnDefs: [
    {name: 'Code', field: 'code', default: 'My default value for code column'},
    {name: 'Name', field: 'name', default: 'My default value for name column'}
];
```

Thanks

Comment: There's an [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/4419) created, no answer yet.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah you can use `cellTemplate`, look that, it's most easy:

```
columnDefs: [
  {name: 'Code', field: 'code', cellTemplate:'<div>{{row.entity.code="My default value for code column"}}</div>'},
  {name: 'Name', field: 'name', cellTemplate:'<div>{{row.entity.name="My default value for name column"}}</div>'}
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `cellTemplates`:

```
  var codeTemplate = '<div ng-if="row.entity.code">{{row.entity.code}}</div>' +
    '<div ng-if="!row.entity.code">My Default Value for code column</div>';

  var nameTemplate = '<div ng-if="row.entity.name">{{row.entity.name}}</div>' +
    '<div ng-if="!row.entity.name">My Default Value for name column</div>';

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableSorting: true,
    columnDefs: [{
      name: 'Code',
      field: 'code',
      cellTemplate: codeTemplate
    }, {
      name: 'Name',
      field: 'name',
      cellTemplate: nameTemplate
    }],
    data: [{
      "code": "122",
      "name": "Maximus"
    }, {
      "code": "123",
      "name": "Minimus"
    }, {
      "code": null,
      "name": "Nocodeus"
    }, {
      "code": '',
      "name": "Emptyus"
    }, {
      "code": '124',
      "name": ""
    }, {
      "code": '',
      "name": ""
    }]
  };
```

Example is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/O1O0jYainjnK0JFUwupN?p=preview)

Comment: This solution would work. However, the columns with custom "cellTemplate"  having issues with filtering. It doesn't work or returns partial results

Answer (score 1):

I achieved it through applying expression to valueFormatter

```
    columnDefs: [
        {name: 'Code', field: 'code', valueFormatter: 'value || My default value for code column'},
        {name: 'Name', field: 'name', valueFormatter: 'value || My default value for name column'}
    ];
```

I think it can also be achieved by applying expression to valueGetter